# Using awk on large txt to extract specific characters of fields

Tags: string, if-statement, text, awk, substring

I have a large txt file ("," as delimiter) with some data and string:

```
2014:04:29:00:00:58:GMT: subject=BMRA.BM.T_GRIFW-1.FPN, message={SD=2014:04:29:00:00:00:GMT,SP=5,NP=3,TS=2014:04:29:01:00:00:GMT,VP=4.0,TS=2014:04:29:01:29:00:GMT,VP=4.0,TS=2014:04:29:01:30:00:GMT,VP=3.0}
2014:04:29:00:00:59:GMT: subject=BMRA.BM.T_GRIFW-2.FPN, message={SD=2014:04:29:00:00:00:GMT,SP=5,NP=2,TS=2014:04:29:01:00:00:GMT,VP=3.0,TS=2014:04:29:01:30:00:GMT,VP=3.0}
```

I would like to find lines that contain 'T_GRIFW' and then print the $1 field from 'subject' onwards and only the times and floats from $2 onwards. Furthermore, I want to incorporate an if statement so that if field $4 == 'NP=3', only fields $5,$6,$9,$10 are printed after the previous fields and if $4 == 'NP=2', all following fields are printed (times and floats only)

For instance, the result of the two sample lines will be:

```
subject=BMRA.BM.T_GRIFW-1.FPN,2014:04:29:00:00:00,5,3,2014:04:29:01:00:00,4.0,2014:04:29:01:30:00,3.0
subject=BMRA.BM.T_GRIFW-2.FPN,2014:04:29:00:00:00,5,2,2014:04:29:01:00:00,3.0,2014:04:29:01:30:00,3.0
```

I know this is complex and I have tried my best to be thorough in my description. The basic code I have thus far is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{OFS=","} /T_GRIFW-1.FPN/ {print $1}' tib_messages.2014-04-29
```

THANKS A MILLION!

Comment: Not much you have so far. Try harder!

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense since it doesn't follow your condition. You said that if `NP=3`, then only fields $5,$6,$9,$10 should print.

Comment: Hi Ooga, sorry for the ambiguity, I meant thereafter, only $5,$6,$9,$10 should print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awk executable file that'll create your desired output:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# use a more complicated FS => field numbers counted differently
BEGIN { FS="=|,"; OFS="," }

$2 ~ /T_GRIFW/ && $8=="NP" {
    str="subject=" $2 OFS

    # strip ":GMT" from dates and "}" from everywhere
    gsub( /:GMT|[\}]/, "")

    # append common fields to str with OFS
    for(i=5;i<=13;i+=2) str=str $i OFS

    # print the remaining fields and line separator
    if($9==3) { print str $19, $21 }
    else if($9==2) { print str $15, $17 }
}
```

Placing that in a file called `awko` and chmod'ing it then running `awko data` yields:

```
subject=BMRA.BM.T_GRIFW-1.FPN,2014:04:29:00:00:00,5,3,2014:04:29:01:00:00,4.0,2014:04:29:01:30:00,3.0
subject=BMRA.BM.T_GRIFW-2.FPN,2014:04:29:00:00:00,5,2,2014:04:29:01:00:00,3.0,2014:04:29:01:30:00,3.0
```

I've placed comments in the script, but here are some things that could be spelled out better:

- Using a more complicated `FS` means you don't have reparse for `=` to work with the field data
- I "cheated" and just hard-coded `subject` (which now falls at the end of `$1`) for `str`
- `:GMT` and `}` appeared to be the only data that needed to be forcibly removed
- With this `FS` Dates and numbers are two apart from each other but still loop-able
- In either final `print` call, the `str` already ends in an `OFS`, so the comma between it and next field can be skipped

Comment: I very happy that some people on here still have great patience with some of us that struggle to learn the ropes! Thanks a lot n0741337 and S. Ahn!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, the following will work:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS=","
}

/T_GRIFW/ {
    split($1, subject, " ")
    result = subject[2] OFS
    delete arr
    counter = 1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        add = 0
        if ($4 == "NP=3") {
            if (i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 10) {
                add = 1
            }
        }
        else if ($4 == "NP=2") {
            add = 1
        }

        if (add) {
            counter = counter + 1
            split($i, field, "=")
            if (match(field[2], "[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|GMT")) {
                arr[counter] = field[2]
            }
        }
    }

    for (i in arr) {
        gsub(/{|}/,"", arr[i]) # remove curly braces
        result = result arr[i] OFS
    }
    print substr(result, 0, length(result)-1)
}
```